# Which is the most spark compatible database for data visualization?

Tags: database, apache-spark

I am using Twitter Steaming and wanted to do visualization for my data. Which is the most compatible and feature enriched database recommended?

Answer (score 1):

You could setup a data pipeline where you fetch and move your data using a tool like [Apache Flume](https://flume.apache.org/) or/and [Apache Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/), analyze it with [Spark](http://spark.apache.org/) and store it in a sink like [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) (or any other NoSql db). After that you can query your data using a visualization tool like [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana).

Comment: can you recommend any database which would be free and can be used with JDBC connector online?

Comment: I would recommend using Apache Phoenix on top of Hbase. https://phoenix.apache.org/